# Mojito beer help

Tags: beer, hops, techniques, ingredients, fruit

I am trying to make a beer that taste kind of like a mojito to try. I am thinking of doing 4lbs 2row and 4lb wheat with a lb of molasses to get around 5% abv. I am just wondering what hops to use and if anyone has an idea of a yeast to use, any comments would be helpful.
Thank you

Comment: Do you mean the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojito cocktail?

Comment: Yes i am talking about the cocktail

Comment: Why don't you make the cocktail instead of trying to make a beer that tastes like a cocktail? Sounds like saying "I want to make chocolate that tastes like sausage".

Answer (score 2):

Hmmn that’s an interesting one I would probably drop the molasses and swap to agave syrup and use Citra hops 3-5 grams and then do a dry hop with a bunch of mint.

Also since a mojito has a very clean flavor profile I would probably do a lager of some sort so that at least narrows down your yeast a little.

Assuming your talking about making a beer like a mojito mixed drink.

edit: Keep us updated I'm interested on how this would turn out.

Comment: Thank you, I will deffinitly look into adding agave i am not sure where to add it and how do you think a kolsh or california common yeast would work?

Comment: you would add agave like any other fermentable, at the end of the boil, and in priming for bottling.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you mean the mojito cocktail, made with mint and lime.

A North Carolina brewery called NoDa Brewing does a mojito-inspired beer called the NoDajito. You might want to look into that for inspiration. They went all the way with the mojito theme and used mint leaves and lime zest.

I'm not quite sure why you'd want to add molasses to the beer, or any adjuncts for that matter. I haven't used molasses personally, but from what I've heard it can give strange flavors when used as more than 5% of the beer. With a whole pound of it in your recipe, you'd have over 10%. If you DO decide to use molasses, you should definitely go for the lighter grade syrup, rather than the darker. With a mojito as a theme, a light beer seems more appropriate.

As for hops, American hops can give a lot of citrusy flavors. Something like Citra, Mosaic or Amarillo may be a good bet. I've tried beer heavy on those hops and it can sometimes taste like they actually had fruit juice added to them. Those hops usually tend to be more grapefruit/orange than lime-flavored, though.

Good luck with the beer! It sounds like it'll be interesting!

Comment: thanks for the input i was planning on the molasses to give the beer a rum flavor, but i will for sure take a look at that NoDajito beer. thanks

Comment: Actually @mpkas seems right - molasses can give a hint of rum taste, expected in mojito. Also, mojito is low on body, and huge adjunct content helps to achieve that as well.

Answer (score 2):

I would use cider yeast (like WLP775 or WYeast 4766). I think strong hop flavors would be out of place, so I would go for aged hops (like people do for p-lambic), and something low-alpha with citrus notes (Strisselspalt would fit the bill).

I agree you should ditch the molasses – mojitos are typically made with white rum, which would not have any molasses flavor. Unrefined cane sugar would be a more appropriate adjunct. Be careful about using too much sugar - the low free amino nitrogen (FAN) can impact yeast health.